# Abelian torsion group of rational points of an elliptic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

I want to find the abelian group of rational points $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}$ of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+8$.

$$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}=\{P \in E(\mathbb{Q}) | P \text{ of finite order }\}$$

From Lutz-Nagell theorem we have the following:

Let $E|_{\mathbb{Q}} , y^2=x^3+ax+b, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $P=(x, y) \in  E(\mathbb{Q})$.

We suppose that $P$ is of finite order.

Then $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y=0$ (that corresponds to the points of order $2$ ) or $y^2 \mid D(f)=4a^3+27b^2$.

We have also the following:

If $P(x, y) \in E(\mathbb{Q})$ and $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ or $y \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then $P$ has infinite order.

$$$$

So, to find the points $P$ of finite order of the curve $y^2=x^3+8$ we do the following:

For $y=0 \Rightarrow x^3+8=0 \Rightarrow x=-2$, $$P=(-2, 0) \in E(\mathbb{Q})$$ of order $2$

Let $f(x)=x^3+8$, then $D(f)=27 \cdot 8^2=2^6 \cdot 3^3$.

$$y^2 \mid 2^6 \cdot 3^3$$

$$2^i, i=0, 2, 4, 6 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3^j, j=0, 2$$

$$y^2 \mid D(f) \Rightarrow y^2=1, 3^2, 2^2, 2^2 \cdot 3^2, 2^4, 2^4 \cdot 3^2, 2^6, 2^6 \cdot 3^2$$

$$ \Rightarrow y=\pm 1 , \pm 3, \pm 2, \pm 2 \cdot 3, \pm 2^2 , \pm 2^2 \cdot 3 , \pm 2^3, \pm 2^3 \cdot 3 \\ \Rightarrow y=\pm 1 , \pm 3, \pm 2, \pm 6, \pm 4 , \pm 12 , \pm 8, \pm 24 $$

For $y=\pm 1 \Rightarrow x^3+7=0 \Rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

For $y=\pm 3 \Rightarrow x^3-1=0 \Rightarrow x=1$, so there are two points with integer coordinates, $P_1=(1, 3), P_2=(1, -3)$.

Does this mean from Lutz-Nagell theorem that these two points are of finite order??

For $y=\pm 2 \Rightarrow x^3+4=0 \Rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

For $y=\pm 6 \Rightarrow x^3-28=0 \Rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

For $y=\pm 4 \Rightarrow x^3-8=0 \Rightarrow x=2$, so there are two points with integer coordinates, $P_3=(2, 4), P_4=(2, -4)$.

Which is the order of these points??

For $y=\pm 12 \Rightarrow x^3-136=0 \Rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

For $y=\pm 8 \Rightarrow x^3-56=0 \Rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

For $y=\pm 24 \Rightarrow x^3-568=0 \Rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The standard way of doing this is to compute $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for a few primes $p$ of good reduction, and to use the fact that the coprime-to-$p$ torsion of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ injects into $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this curve the torsion points are $P = (-2, 0)$ of order $2$ and the point at infinity. The reason why your points $P_1, ..., P_4$ are not torsion points are due to the fact that the Nagell-Lutz Theorem only gives you the possible candidates for the torsion points. In other words, Nagell-Lutz is not a *if and only if*-theorem.

When checking the list of possible torsion points, then if a point $P$ has order greater than $12$ then that point has infinite order. So you need to check if $nP = \mathcal{O}$, for $2 \leq n \leq 12$. If not, then $P$ has infinite order. This is due to the celebrated theorem of Barry Mazur, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_torsion_theorem).

Comment: So, do we use this: From Mazur's theorem we have the following: 

If $E |_{\mathbb{Q}}: y^2=x^3+ax+b, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ an elliptic curve, then $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } n=1, 2, \dots ,10, 12$$ 
or $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } m=1, 2, 3, 4$$ ??

Comment: Does it stand that if for example $2P$ is of infinite order, then $P$ is also of infinite order??

Comment: We are using both cases. If you look at all the points in the $15$ possible torsion groups then you will see that the maximal order of an element is $12$ which occurs in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: I will do my best. From Nagell-Lutz you will get at set of points $P_1, ..., P_k$. You know that you must find the torsion points among those points, but you don't know that all points are indeed torsion points. Therefore, you need to check the order of each point to see if the order is finite. From Mazur's theorem you also know that the torsion group is one of $15$ possible groups and among all elements in the $15$ groups in Mazur's theorem you will find no element with order larger than $12$. Therefore you check for each of the points from Nagell-Lutz if the order is below $12$...

Comment: ... If the order of a point is not $\leq 12$ then the order must be infinite, as it cannot be an element in the $15$ groups in Mazur's theorem. If anything is still unclear, let me know what is not clear, and I'll explain further.

Comment: To clarify something... $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } n=1, 2, \dots , 10, 12$$ means that the torsion group $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}$ contains the points $P$ which have the identity $$nP=0, \text{ for } n=1, 2, \dots , 10, 12$$ and the coordinates are integers, right ?? And what does $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } m=1, 2, 3, 4$$ mean??

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to rephrase to hopefully clarify in some detail how to use the Nagell-Lutz theorem and Mazur's theorem to find the torsion group.

So we work with the points $P_i$ that we find from Nagell-Lutz. We add $P_i$ to itself atmost $12$ times, that is for each $P_i$ we calculate the set $\{nP_i \text{ | }  2 \leq n \leq 12\}$. If in this set we find the point at infinity $\mathcal{O}$, we know that $P_i$ has finite order, by definition of a point of finite order. If we don't find $\mathcal{O}$ the order of $P_i$ must be $> 12$ and we conclude that the order of $P_i$ is infinite by Mazur's theorem.

Also to answer your last question, if $2P$ has infinite order then $P$ also has infinite order, because the torsion group is a subgroup. Or we can prove this easily by proof of contradiction.

Assume $2P$ has infinite order and assume to the contrary that $P$ has finite order. This means that we can find $n$ such that $nP = \mathcal{O}$. Then we calculate $n(2P) = 2(nP) = 2\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}$, so $2P$ has finite order, which contradicts our assumption. So $P$ must have infinite order.

Comment: So to find which of the possible points, that we found from Lutz-Nagell theorem, are in the torsion group do we have to add the point $P$ at itself at most $10$ times to check if the order is $\leq 12$ ?? We have that if $P(x, y) \in E(\mathbb{Q})$ and $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ or $y \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then $P$ has infinite order... If for example we find that the coordinates of $2P$ are rational, that means that $2P$ has infinite order, does this mean that $P$ has also infinite order??

Comment: I'll edit my answer above to hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Is anything still unclear after my last edit? :)

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)